# Screen Recording of Google Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, screencast

I am developing a chrome extension. I want to record the browser tab of google chrome as video for a specific time as ScreenCastify chrome extension do. How would I do that in my chrome extension.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. how to write a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask also there is already many related answers in s.o. if you search

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**ScreenCastify** uses `chrome.desktopCapture` API.